# How can I use mingw to build mkspiffs?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, build, mingw

I'm trying to build [mkspiffs](https://github.com/igrr/mkspiffs) for windows. It's a c/c++ project. I installed mingw, and added it to my path.

The README.md says to run

```
$ git submodule update --init
$ make dist
```

The `make dist` command gives me the following output:

```
File not found - *.c
cc -std=gnu99 -Os -Wall -mno-ms-bitfields  -Itclap -Iinclude -Ispiffs/src -I. -D VERSION=\"0.2.3-6-g983970e\" -D SPIFFS_VERSION=\"0.3.7-5-gf5e26c4\" -D BUILD_CONFIG=\"\" -D BUILD_CONFIG_NAME=\"-generic\" -D __NO_INLINE__   -c -o spiffs/src/spiffs_cache.o spiffs/src/spiffs_cache.c
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -std=gnu99 -Os -Wall -mno-ms-bitfields -Itclap -Iinclude -Ispiffs/src -I. -D VERSION=\"0.2.3-6-g983970e\" -D SPIFFS_VERSION=\"0.3.7-5-gf5e26c4\" -D BUILD_CONFIG=\"\" -D BUILD_CONFIG_NAME=\"-generic\" -D __NO_INLINE__ -c -o spiffs/src/spiffs_cache.o spiffs/src/spiffs_cache.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [spiffs/src/spiffs_cache.o] Error 2
```

I'm using mingw64.

```
C:\Users\peterkapteyn>where gcc
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
```

I am a novice when it comes to building things from source/using makefiles and that sort of thing. Can anyone offer some insight into what's going on?

Comment: Try `make CC=gcc CXX=g++`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!